# How can I get the same output about merge conflicts as from the merge command?

Tags: git, merge

When I first attempt the merge which turns out to have conflicts, I get an output in a very useful and readable format:

```
CONFLICT (rename/delete): Folder/Folder/file.txt deleted in branch_to_merge and renamed in HEAD. Version HEAD of Folder/Folder/file.txt left in tree.
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in Folder/Folder/file2.txt
```

However, when I run `git status` or `git ls-files -u` afterwards, it displays the merge state in other formats, which I personally find less useful.

Can I get that output again without restarting the merge process?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
git diff --name-only --diff-filter=U
```

I have been using for various conflict case. For example, when a cherry-pick fails with a conflict in config.js, I run it and get the following output:

```
> git cherry-pick xxxxxxx..yyyyyyy
error: could not apply xxxxxxx... implement feature mmm
hint: after resolving the conflicts, mark the corrected paths
hint: with 'git add <paths>' or 'git rm <paths>'
hint: and commit the result with 'git commit'

> git diff --name-only --diff-filter=U
config/config.js
```

BTW, I've set an alias `conflict` for it in my `~/.gitconfig`:

```
[alias]
  conflict = diff --name-only --diff-filter=U
```